# Drarry Harry Potter fanfic, Draco or Harry de-ages and gets gradually older from doses of potions Snape gives him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I have read it before but I can’t find it or remember its title.

Either Harry or Draco were de-aged, I think it’s Draco but it could be Harry, and Harry looks after him in a room of their own.

Dumbledore has placed clothing already and Harry dresses a little Draco but Snape can only administer the potion in doses so he gets gradually older like from a baby to a toddler to a young child to a teen to normal age. It could be Harry who got younger actually I can’t remember.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if [Malfoy Child by Biza](https://archiveofourown.org/works/10532211/chapters/23252910) is the fic that you are looking for, but it sounds somewhat similar. It has Draco becoming de-aged after a potions accident and Harry taking him under his wing, but I believe they stay in the Gryffindor dorm and not their own room.

> A potions accident turns Draco into a four-year-old and Harry takes
>   over his care for the next four months.